# Remove "Smoothness" in outer theme

Tags: beamer, presentations, themes

I'm using this code here:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
%\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax}{}{}{}
%\def\beamer@subsectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{\advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax}%
%\makeatother

%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[
    audience=english
]{beameraudience}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Cannot enable in Xelatex
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% \setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
% \setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
% \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,stackengine}

%% Enable only in Xelatex
% \usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\author{Micha Christ}
\title{Kalman Bayesian Neural Network: An in-depth Revision and Extension to Convolutional Architectures}
\institute [Media Univsersity Stuttgart, Fraunhofer IPA] {Media Univsersity Stuttgart\\Center for Cyber Cognitive Intelligence, Fraunhofer IPA}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\scriptsize}
\usepackage{YTU}
\graphicspath{{pic/}}
% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{gr}{HTML}{2f6e5a}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
    \oldmacro\hfill%
    }

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

which gives me the following header:

[image]

Without changing the footer or anything else, how can I remove the smoothness of of the second (light green) header bar?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Especially, is the package `YTU` available somewhere?

Comment: Also, what is the "smoothness" you refer to in your question? Teh color gradient between the dark and the lighter green area, as well as the color gradient between the light green bar and the white background? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the frametitle like this:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
%\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax}{}{}{}
%\def\beamer@subsectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{\advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax}%
%\makeatother

%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[
    audience=english
]{beameraudience}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Cannot enable in Xelatex
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% \setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
% \setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
% \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,stackengine}

%% Enable only in Xelatex
% \usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\author{Micha Christ}
\title{Kalman Bayesian Neural Network: An in-depth Revision and Extension to Convolutional Architectures}
\institute [Media Univsersity Stuttgart, Fraunhofer IPA] {Media Univsersity Stuttgart\\Center for Cyber Cognitive Intelligence, Fraunhofer IPA}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\scriptsize}
\usepackage{YTU}
\graphicspath{{pic/}}
% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{gr}{HTML}{2f6e5a}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
    \oldmacro\hfill%
    }

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-0.19ex%
  \usebeamerfont{headline}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,vmode]{frametitle}
    \vskip0.5ex%
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\strut\insertframetitle%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \strut\par%
      \else
        \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\strut\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi%%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \vskip0.05ex%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]